# Why will my macro only work when I run it from the macro dialog box?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two macros that I want to work when I push a button. I inserted the code needed in the button sub and made it so that it is not private. Then I opened the macro dialog box and ran the macro and it worked as expected. But, when I try to press the button, it comes up with an error that says "the requested member of the collection does not exist."

The code shouldn't really matter in this case since it is working correctly when I run it manually but here it is:

```
Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  Selection.Tables(1).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 24

  'Some other Code here

End Sub
```

When I perform a debug, it says that the problem is in this line: `Selection.Tables(1).Select`

Then in my other instance I have this code:

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Selection.SelectRow
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
  Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

The code error appears to be in this line:

```
Selection.SelectRow
```

It says

> The SelectRow method or property is not available because some or all of the object does not refer to a table.

I got the code by using the `Macro Recorder`.

If you have any ideas as to why this is happening, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess that as soon as you press the button, `Selection` does now point to that button instead of the table you want to work with. Please try replacing `Selection.Tables(1)...` with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)...` and see what happens.

Comment: @Verzweifler  `ActiveDocument,Tables(1)...` refers to the First Table in the ActiveDocument

Comment: WHERE is the button that you click, exactly? Should this macro run always on a specific table, or on any table in the document?

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
Selection.Tables(1)
```

works only when the Selection (the cursor) is inside a table.

When you click the button, the button gets the focus, and the Selection is moved there. If the button is not inside a table, the code will fail.

It does work if you move the button inside the table, but that would probably look silly.

Comment: `Selection.Tables(1)` will also work if you are in the `Line` following the `Table` and it will `Select` the `Table` above the `Line`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
 Selection.SelectRow
```

with

```
 'r being which ever row you want to Select
 Selection.Table(1).Row(r).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your macro to a key combination. This won't change any focus you've set, and thus should solve your problem.

How to do this differs among different versions of Word, but the recent versions are explained here:

http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008058_Assigning_a_Macro_to_a_Shortcut_Key.html